# How to define a static member in case there is not header file?

Tags: c++, static

How to define a static member in case there is not header file ?

The code:

```
class MyClass
{
};

int MyClass::staticMember;  // Error: class MyClass has no member staticMember!
```

Any help?

Comment: You just declare it wherever your class declaration is. Doesn't matter if it's in a header file or not.

Comment: @Jon :Can't I not have a class declaration ?

Comment: @Jack: Not if you want the class to exist. Are you trying to use it in a manner more suited to a `namespace`?

Comment: Remember: "header" != "[declaration](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1410563/what-is-the-difference-between-a-definition-and-a-declaration/1410632#1410632)"

Answer (score 6, accepted):

This will work:

```
//
// Inside .cpp file
//
class MyClass
{
    static int staticMember;
};

int MyClass::staticMember;
```

Comment: Probably want `staticMember` to be declared `public` or have accessors. Indeed, the desire for accessors would be the main reason to use a `class` here rather than a named or un-named `namespace`.

Answer (score 2):

If it's not in the class declaration, you can't define it.